# Можно ли считать придаточное общим элементом (вопрос о запятой перед И)

Tags: запятые, и

Предложение:

***Так как оплата прошла через приложение, нам потребуется помощь технической поддержки и мы не можем прямо сейчас вернуть баллы.***

Нужна ли запятая? Вот так:

***Так как оплата прошла через приложение, нам потребуется помощь технической поддержки (,) и мы не можем прямо сейчас вернуть баллы.***

Является ли "Так как оплата прошла через приложение" обобщающим?

- Так как оплата прошла через приложение, нам потребуется помощь технической поддержки
- Так как оплата прошла через приложение, мы не можем прямо сейчас вернуть баллы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе здесь возможны **оба решения**, но я бы поставила запятую.

**1. Пояснение**

*(1) **Так как оплата прошла через приложение**, (2) нам потребуется помощь технической поддержки, (3) и мы не можем прямо сейчас вернуть баллы.*

В этом случае у нас **два сообщения**: причина задержки (нужна техническая помощь) и следствие из ситуации (из-за этого не можем вернуть деньги сразу).

Тогда предложения (1) и (2) составляют **СПП с придаточным причины**, причем придаточное стоит на первом месте. А это означает бОльшую взаимообусловленность главного и придаточного предложений (они как бы теснее связаны).

Также простые предложения (2) и (3) п**о грамматике неоднородны** (формы глаголов разные, будущее и настоящее время).

**2.** **Как еще проверить вариант решения?** Попробуем для этого использовать подчинительную и бессоюзную  связь с наречием "поэтому".

Это ответ на заданный вопрос: *Вы можете вернуть мне баллы?*

*Так как оплата прошла через приложение, то нам потребуется помощь технической поддержки, **поэтому** мы не можем прямо сейчас вернуть баллы*. Здесь **общим следствием** является предложение (3).